# Simple question about notation of forms in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Does it make sense to call a rank (n   k) tensor a k-form if it is antisymmetric in its lower indices and n is *not* equal to 0? Or is the word form reserved for (0   k) antisymmetric tensors?

Comment: are you referring to vector valued differential forms ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form

Comment: Yes indeed, this is what I was looking for. Thank you!